# Configuração do IIS para autenticar utilizando Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

Criei um sistema web utilizando C# e utilizo uma rotina para autenticar o usuário pegando o usuário do Active Directory.
Porém meu sistema não está pegando o usuário AD: ele está pegando o usuário do *pool* da aplicação.
Quando eu rodo o sistema localmente na minha máquina a rotina funciona perfeitamente, porém quando subo o sistema para o servidor acontece esse problema.

A rotina que utilizo é essa:

```
// Cria um contexto principal para definir a busca na base do AD.
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// Cria uma query do Active Directory Domain Services.
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(principalContext.ConnectedServer);

// Cria um filtro para a busca com o login do usuário da rede.
directorySearcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + System.Environment.UserName + ")";

/*
* Cria um elemento da hierarquia do Active Directory.
* Este elemento é retornado durante uma busca através de DirectorySearcher.
*/
SearchResult searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();

// Cria um objeto encapsulado da hierarquia de diretório serviços do AD.
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

return directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
```

Estou utilizando o IIS 7.0.

Comment: O método de autenticação com o AD está instalado no servidor roda o IIS?

Comment: Sim, @AndreMesquita , estou achando que o problema pode estar na configuração do IIS, você sabe configurar o IIS para autenticar com o usuário AD?

Comment: Se a aplicação é ASP.NET MVC, não seria apenas o caso de usar `<authentication mode="Windows" />` no `web.config`? Por que você precisa verificar o diretório do Active Directory?

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126506/20615) lhe ajuda. Ela também possui um link de como configurar o `IIS` para esse tipo autenticação.